# Can't save subassembly "THE SELECTED PART IS NOT ATTACHABLE!"

Tags: kerbal-space-program

When trying to save a 'science prob' (see below image), I keep getting the above message and can't save it.

*Action taken to produce result:* Build the module (see image), drag and drop the OKTO pod to the 'drop zone'.

What might be the reason and can it be saved?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing the 'root' part? The last of those four buttons next to pieces list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save full (component-wise) ships as subassemblies. Basically they need to be parts of a ship, where the piece you save from (the piece you click and drag over to the subassemblies section) has to be a piece that connects multiple pieces together, like a stack separator/decoupler. I'm not sure that you can have any kind of a command probe or module in a subassembly.

Comment: You definitely can have a command module (eg. Probodobodyne) as a subassembly.

Comment: Sounds, after thinking of it, if one could, he could duplicate a ship and ends up with 2+ ships in the construction yard & launch pad, 10x!!

Comment: @ShloEmi You can do that, but the ships have to be connected. And, of course, then you need the thrust to get into orbit. But I've seen people do this to spam all the biomes on Mun in a single launch.

Comment: @Coomie nice, have any screenshot of that?

Comment: @ShloEmi It was actually a youtube video. I had a good search for it and still couldn't find it. As I recall it was a monstrosity of a ship with 20ish powered probes hanging off everywhere.

Comment: @Coomie Actually, it's can be a practice idea to have a spaceship that is in orbit and detaches N probes, each have a different fuel and/or different max acceleration pre-defined and when detached they automatically start a small engine, so the result will be: each prob will get into different orbit, and different altitude and different time to complete a cycle :-)

Comment: 1) you can have a whole ship saved as subassembly but the root part must have a free node. 2) The "multiple disconnected ships on launchpad at once" is a trick entirely apart from the subassembly requirements, resulting from abuse of the offset tool - still one ship, but not continuous. (people make airplane squadrons that way; a single "craft" composed of three airplanes offset by several meters from each other). If you want genuinely separate crafts, you need to deploy them as one, then undock/decouple. 3) a loaded subassembly is "ghosted" until attached and won't appear on the launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to re-root to the engine where you're attaching (probably a launch vehicle).  I ran into this when making a combination of lander and tanker.  The lander lands with nearly no fuel on the mun, but launches a tanker to transport fuel and kerbals back to the lander if needed.  But now you'll have a mun base that can transport fuel to any similar designed lander (and if you made your mun base correctly, can practically make fuel at will.).

Once I re-rooted to the poodle engine, I was able to save it as a sub-assembly called lander_tanker.  I'll let you know my success when I put it on the mun in career mode.